# jquery drag and drop in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a table with 5 rows and have data in it is there any drag and drop functionality in jquery that i can use to change the order of data inside the table since I am new to jquery i dont have any idea in how to implement this any help

Comment: What have you done/tried so far? This was a rather thin explanation.

Comment: I have created the table with the contents in it now need to start writing the jquery functions to implement it

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with the use of jQuery UI.

Sample Table:

```
<table class="list">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="sep">
            <td>Foobar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Sample JS:

```
$('table.list tbody').sortable({
    disabled: false,
    items: 'tr.sep',
    // handle: 'span.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s',
    opacity: 0.7,
    axis: 'y',
    forceHelperSize: true,
    update: function( e, ui ) {
        var currentTr = ui.item;
        // do some stuff...
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: It says that object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Try it without the .disableSelection(). Be sure you've loaded jQuery + jQuery UI in your Document.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI supports drag and drop. Is that any good for you?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

You will need to download JQuery UI and include in your project. It's a plugin to the main JQuery project so needs to be included in your pages separately

http://jqueryui.com/download

Or perhaps the sort table function might be better

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not good enough for my requirement i need to drag and drop inside a table which contains a many rows

Comment: @Mathew Paul I've added another link. if it's any help